How do I call who specifically clicked on links in a campaign in MailChimp?
I am currently using the MailChimp API to gather some data about my reports in PowerBI.
One of the things I am struggling with is creating an API call in PowerBI that iterates through every campaign, then every link within that campaign, and then to return who has clicked on that link (on email address).
I have tried querying /email-activity/ but I cannot get the numbers to tie up with the aggregated figures on my MailChimp dashboard.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
